# Best way to replace Urls in .Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an application developed in ASP.NET Core C#, where according to a configuration it must replace certain urls of a text when an http request is made and the text must be returned as soon as possible in response, the text can change on each request.

At this moment the code I have is working well, but I would like you to help me check the code to improve the speed of replacement of the urls.

```
string r = contenidoRespuesta; //contenidoRespuesta can be html, json or javascript content
string dominio="example.com";
int puertoHttp=81,puertoHttps=444;           
foreach (var p in grupo.Paginas.Where(p => p.Proxy))
{

    Uri uri = new Uri(p.URL);
    string pattern1 = string.Format("(?<=https://){0}(:(443)(?!\\d+))?(?!:)", uri.Host);//generates a regular expression to replace urls that start with "https"
    string pattern2 = string.Format("(?<=http://){0}(:(80)(?!\\d+))?(?!:)", uri.Host);//generates a regular expression to replace urls that start with "http"
    string pattern3 = string.Format("(?<!%2F|\\.|http(s)?(://)){0}(:((80)|(443))(?!\\d+))?(?!:)", uri.Host);//generates a regular expression to replace urls that start with "//"


    r = Regex.Replace(r, pattern1,uri.Host.Replace(".", string.Empty) + "." +dominio + ":" + puertoHttps, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);// replace https://www.page.com for https://wwwpagecom.example.com
    r = Regex.Replace(r, pattern2,uri.Host.Replace(".", string.Empty) + "." + dominio + ":" + puertoHttp, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);// replace http://www.page.com for http://wwwpagecom.example.com
    r = Regex.Replace(r, pattern3, uri.Host.Replace(".", string.Empty) + "." + dominio + ":" +(esquema == "https"? puertoHttps.ToString(): puertoHttp.ToString()));// replace //www.page.com for https://wwwpagecom.example.com
}
return r;//return the responsd with new urls
```

Comment: Could you please provide the configuration requirements ?, and is this for a web api application ? is the current method  is executed from an api request ?

Comment: Yes it is a web application and the method is executed every time the client makes a request. In each request the application consults information from another page (according to the subdomain) and replaces the previously configured urls, so that new requests continue to be made to the same server, it works as a web proxy. _contenidoRespuesta_ is the response from the website in which I should replace the urls

Comment: So basically you're routing the web requests from current server to another server. Is that true?  If true, why you didn't use Routing ?

Comment: See this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: It is not done by routing because the number of pages to be used depends on each client and can change at any time, in addition to doing some additional operations and this allows me to have it centralized. Now, what I want to improve (the method) is not in the requests, it is when processing the response, I need to replace the urls as quickly as possible,so that the response time is not affected.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just getting the host url, remove the dots, then append it as a subdomain to the given domain with the approprate protocols (Https or Http). You can do this :

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetRoutedUrls(IEnumerable<string> urls, string domain, int httpPort, int httpsPort)
{
    if(urls == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(urls)); }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(domain)); }

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) { yield return null; }

       if(Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out Uri uri))
        {
            yield return uri.Scheme == "https" ? $"https://{uri.Host.Replace(".", string.Empty)}.{domain}:{httpsPort}" : $"http://{uri.Host.Replace(".", string.Empty)}.{domain}:{httpPort}";
        }
    }
}
```

usage :

```
var urls = GetRoutedUrls(grupo.Paginas.Where(p => p.Proxy).Select(x=> x.URL), "example.com", 81, 444)
```

**UPDATE**

After clarifying things, I think you don't need Regex since you're replacing an exact match of urls. Regex would be more useful if you want to search for unknown inputs.

To give you an example of that, if we want to get every single url in the response we can use

```
Regex.Matches(response, @"(https?://)(.*)(\d)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

This would get every single url that has specified a port (e.g. `https://example.com:443`). Then, we can do stuff on them.

In your method, is different a bit. You already have defined the urls, and you want to check for these urls in your response, if they exist, you want to change them by appending them as subdomain to the given domain, and giving them a new port as well.

Unless if there is any special cases that is not covered or mentioned in your post (which forced you to use Regex in first place), I think it would be a straight forward approach if we just use `string.Replace` directly.

```
public string ReplaceResponseUrls(IEnumerable<string> urls, string response, string domain, int httpPort, int httpsPort)
{
    if (urls == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(urls)); }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(response)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(response)); }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(domain)); }

    var responseStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(response);

    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) { continue; } // skip to the next url

        if (Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out Uri uri))
        {
            responseStringBuilder.Replace(
                $"{uri.Scheme}://{uri.Host}:{uri.Port}", // old url
                $"{uri.Scheme}://{uri.Host.Replace(".", string.Empty)}.{domain}:{(uri.Scheme == "https" ? httpsPort : httpPort)}" // new url
                );
        }
    }

    return responseStringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Try this approach first, do some tests on it, and let me know if you need any help with it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your collaboration, but if you check my code, the variable "r" originally has a text and that text (html or json) is what I return after I replace the urls. Your code could be used to generate the replacement patterns, but it does not include the third pattern that is with when the url does not have the established scheme, in the form "//www.example.com".

Comment: I wrote some comments in my code for you to understand better

Comment: @German just a question before I update it, is it mandatory to have an exact match of `uri.Host`?  or do you intend to search for all urls in the response and replace them all  ?  The only reason that cam up to my head for that is the response may have some other urls that are not related to the context, and you only want to replace specific urls and ignore the rest. Is that what you're trying to do ?

Comment: Yeah that's right. I just need to replace the urls that match **"uri.Host"**, the rest should be ignored.

Comment: @German check out the update.

Comment: The main reason why I didn't use `uri.Scheme` and `uri.Port` in my code is because in the http response I must make sure to replace all possible schemas: **"https"**, **"http"** or **"//"**. Also, it is possible that some urls have the port or not, which is why I used Regex. your code will only replace the exact urls in the current schema and port, but it will not replace the other schemas or when the port is not in the url.

Answer (score 1):

It seems changing the regex is not solution, my suggestions:

- get rid of the `r` variable, it is swelling the memory and makes slow the response time(of course, if value of the parameter `contenidoRespuesta` is not needed anymore).
- we don't know the content of `html`/`json`/`js`, so next cases indicate assumptions.
- i wondering in your `contenidoRespuesta` variable can matches with different regex patterns on the same data? if it is not or even there exists the posibility, i suggest you to use if statement seperately to reducing the response time.
- if always one regex match exists, you can use if/else statement to reducing much more the response time.
- i did some tests with lack of mock data which shows performance of if statement. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ooLrYH

```c#
    //string r = contenidoRespuesta; //decrease the responsee time after RegexReplace succeed
    string dominio = "example.com";
    int puertoHttp = 81, puertoHttps = 444;
        foreach (var p in grupo.Paginas.Where(p => p.Proxy))
        {
             Uri uri = new Uri(p.URL);
             string pattern1 = string.Format("(?<=https://){0}(:(443)(?!\\d+))?(?!:)", uri.Host); //changing to static method with Regex.Replace may good
             string pattern2 = string.Format("(?<=http://){0}(:(80)(?!\\d+))?(?!:)", uri.Host);  //changing to static method with Regex.Replace may good
             string pattern3 = string.Format("(?<!%2F|\\.|http(s)?(://)){0}(:((80)|(443))(?!\\d+))?(?!:)", uri.Host);  //changing to static method with Regex.Replace may good


             //if (new Regex(pattern1).Match(contenidoRespuesta).Success)//positive effects a bit
              contenidoRespuesta= Regex.Replace(contenidoRespuesta, pattern1, uri.Host.Replace(".", string.Empty) + "." + dominio + ":" + puertoHttps, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);// replace https://www.page.com for https://wwwpagecom.example.com
             //if (new Regex(pattern2).Match(contenidoRespuesta).Success)//positive effects a bit
              contenidoRespuesta= Regex.Replace(contenidoRespuesta, pattern2, uri.Host.Replace(".", string.Empty) + "." + dominio + ":" + puertoHttp, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);// replace http://www.page.com for http://wwwpagecom.example.com
            // if (new Regex(pattern3).Match(contenidoRespuesta).Success)//positive effects a bit
              contenidoRespuesta= Regex.Replace(contenidoRespuesta, pattern3, uri.Host.Replace(".", string.Empty) + "." + dominio + ":" + (esquema == "https" ? puertoHttps.ToString() : puertoHttp.ToString()));// replace //www.page.com for https://wwwpagecom.example.com
        }
return contenidoRespuesta;
```

Comment: The `Regex.Replace` method internally executes the `Regex.Match` method before replacing any text, therefore it is unnecessary to use the  `if`  statement.

Comment: that is wrong Regex.Replace `returns whole data `even result `false` so moving values from somewhere to another place means extra `work` so performance will be affected. if condition checks then returns `true/false` you should do some tests.

Comment: Remember that `string` is a reference type, therefore when executing the `Replace` method and there are no matches it returns the same reference, values ​​are not being moved to another place.

Comment: i noticed but it's rerecence will change when you modified the `r`,so they will not have same reference.  check with `Object.ReferenceEquals(r, contenidoRespuesta);` before `return r;` so it still swelling the memory and it says performance decreasing.

Comment: It is correct and that is the reason for my question, how to improve that ?, I have not found another way to do it, when executing the `Replace` method, if there is a match, it will return a new reference, but otherwise it will return the same reference, so it is unnecessary to use the `if` statement before `Replace` since internally it executes the `Match` method.